# How to change just piece of component in angular 2 and don't render again some things

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create an application with `angular 2`.

I have a profile account for users. In this component I have a `header` and a cover picture exactly like Facebook. When the user clicks the *about* tab or another tab I want to just render related content for this tab, but I don't want to render `header` and `cover` and `tabs` again.

How to make this work?

I do this is my `appComponent` using  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` like this:

```
<header></header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

But I don't know how it's possible in another component. Can somebody show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a second router-outlet in the profile component.

I understand you have a **ProfileComponent**. In that component you specify the configuration of the second router with @Routes (or @RouteConfig); you will probably have as many route configuration entries as are the tabs you want to control (one entry per tab).

Then you place  in the template of **ProfileComponent** where it is convenient and use it as you use the root **AppComponent**.

I hope this is clear enough and it helps

Comment: and second @RouteConfig ? how??!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271203/i-want-use-aux-routing-in-angular-2-but-i-have-probelem
see my question..
i cant understand how config my routes in child component !

Comment: I sugget you to follow the step by step guide [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html#] ; it shows also how to configure a child router